# Ubuntu freezes while playing any type of multimedia

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, skype, vlc, multimedia

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Lenovo Z510. When playing multimedia, the screen freezes, but the sound goes on. It happens with VLC video, Image Viewer, and Skype. Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Comment: You need proprietary Nvidia drivers for optimal performance. You can find the recommended one in Additional Drivers.

Comment: I disabled the Nvidia graphics card, I'm using only the integrated one. Everything was fine until today, but today I experienced the freeze 5 times so far.

Comment: The Intel one should be more than enough. Install all the updates and reboot.

Comment: I had the similar issue with chrome browser, I disabled gpu hardware acceleration in the browser settings, ever since no freezing.

Comment: you can try  `libvdpau-va-gl1` package, if it's installed you can try that driver to run an app like `VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox` . More info here http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/enable-hardware-acceleration-on-intel-graphics-cards-in-ubuntu/